# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Freerdp smartcard problem

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu, lsusb, xfreerdp, smartcard

We use Ubuntu 16.04 and we must run e-sign card on Windows Server 2012 Terminal Server. 
I installed `libccid`, `libusb-0.1-4`, `pcscd`, `libpcsclite1` packages, and I see device of `lsusb` output.

```
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux
 Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 002 Device 004: ID 072f:90cc Advanced
 Card Systems, Ltd ACR38 SmartCard Reader Bus 002 Device 003: ID
 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub Bus 002 Device 002: ID
 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001
 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I use this parameter connect the server via `freerdp`,

```
xfreerdp /v:xxx.xxx.xx /d:xxx.xxx.xx /smartcard:"ACS ACR U38-CCID 00 00"
```

If I connect the server and smartcard connect the physically my remote is freeze than I unplug card and again plug the usb socket always fine.

than, I connect the server without smartcard always fine, after connect the card again always fine.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.
I removed `libpcsclite1` and `pcscd` packages, and install debian versions.

```
Pcscd --> 1.8.14-1ubuntu1.16.04.1 --> pcscd_1.8.13-1+de8u1-amd64
libpcsclite1 --> 1.8.14-1ubuntu1.16.04.1 --> libpcsclite1_1.8.13-1+de8u1_amd64
```